# setInterval pauses in iphone/ipad (mobile Safari) during scrolling

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, setinterval

I use the setInterval function in a website, and it works fine in IE, Chrome, Firefox and Safari. When i try it on ipad/iphone (safari mobile) i get problem: if i scroll the screen, the setInterval function pauses and it resumes only when i stop scrolling!

is there a way to prevent the function from pausing?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid no, there's no way to prevent such behaviour. There's a plenty of topics here in SO about this problem (more-o-less related), here's a particularly [interesting one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225525/how-can-i-monitor-scroll-position-while-scrolling-in-safari-on-ios). Its summary is simple:

> iOS elastic scroll can't be tracked. There's no event listener for it
>   + both timeout / interval doesn't execute during scroll. And because there's no requestAnimationFrame in iOS5, this seems impossible to
>   solve.

Comment: i hope they will solve it in iOS 6, however thank you very much!

Comment: This issue has not been resolved in iOS6 - all Javascript is simply paused during elastic scroll and not resumed until the scrolling stops (and onScroll is fired).

Comment: Seems to be fixed in iOS 6.1

Answer (score 1):

iOS6 Safari suffers from a bug that kills timers that are created while a page is scrolling.

There is a fix to this problem provided by kTmnh by recreating timers after scrolling finishes

https://gist.github.com/3798925.

Answer (score 0):

Check @Pattishall answer on this subject
[iOS 6 js events function not called if has setTimeout in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855123/ios-6-js-events-function-not-called-if-has-settimeout-in-it)