# Why does Javascript pause when long pressing on an Android or iOS device?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, webview

When I long press or scroll on the screen of an Android or iOS device, the Javascript running in the webview pauses. How can I keep js running, and additionally, why does js pause in this case?

Comment: may be optimization concerns

Comment: To some extent, I think it is not good optimization.

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177774/setinterval-pauses-in-iphone-ipad-mobile-safari-during-scrolling) has a similar question/answer, I believe it is purely a performance optimisation, as scrolling will require the browser to redraw/paint the DOM: This will take alot of resources. In regards to the long press, this may be related to the browser waiting to understand what the wants to do next, i.e. selecting an area to copy/paste or triggering the browsers context menu.