# How to keep timer running while user touch screen?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios

This simple JavaScript stop/pauses when the user touch the screen on both iOS and Android devices. I am soon giving up why does so, how do I fix this? I need the timer to be running even though the user scrolls.

```
    window.setInterval(function () {
        console.log("Hello, Why Is This Not WORKING!");
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [setInterval pauses in iphone/ipad (mobile Safari) during scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177774/setinterval-pauses-in-iphone-ipad-mobile-safari-during-scrolling)

Comment: But I don't want the timers to pause at all.

Comment: From that question: "is there a way to prevent the function from pausing?"