# Countdown pause on scrolling on mobile devices but not on desktop

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, angularjs

I am building a web app that is intended to run on mobile phones and desktop. A part of the app is a quiz. I have a countdown clock at the top of the page that counts down one seconds at the time.

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    console.log("THIS STOPS WHILE SCROLLING");
}, 1000);
```

When the user touches the screen and holds on Android and iOS devices, this function pauses and then resumes when scrolling or touching is done/released.

I need the clock to keep updating and counting while the user touches the screen. How do I do that? I am using `AngularJS`.

Comment: You probably won't like this but: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177774/setinterval-pauses-in-iphone-ipad-mobile-safari-during-scrolling

Comment: There's a claim there that it's fixed in iOS 6.1 though

Comment: This does not only apply to iOS. That question/answer is about the timers no longer is deleted on scroll as far as I understood it. The same thing is happening in Android.

Comment: Oh, my bad then. I got curious about this and googled a bit and from reading that question/answer it seemed like it was the same issue as yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable scrolling on touch devices using code like this:

```
var disableScroll = function (e) {
    if (yourAlarmIsRunning === true) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
};

document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', disableScroll, false);
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', disableScroll, false);
```

Since it sounds like you only want to disable it if your alarm thing is running, use a variable to keep track of whether it's running, and if it is, then disable scrolling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I need to be able to scroll. The timer will run for 45 minutes at the top of the screen while the user is answering question. He/she must be able to scroll on the screen.

Comment: @LuckyLuke In that case, no, there's no way to do that. Scrolling is handled by the browser, and has nothing exposed to us as JS developers in regards to what happens internally (in this case, setIntervals working funnily because of scrolling)

Comment: Damn. Do you know about other ways to track the time on the client side without these pauses? It is a quiz and I need to know how long a user have spent.

Comment: Sure. You could use delta timing. So when your timer starts, you store `Date.now()` in a variable. And whenever your setInterval happens to fire, you subtract `Date.now()` from the original time. [A simple example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Bavmf/) Using this, you don't rely on the actual timeout to tell how much time has passed, you rely on the actual time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some "scroll" library, to emulate the native scroll. This way, the timeouts and intervals aren't paused ;)

I had the same problem in the past, and this worked for me.

I don't remember exactly wich library i used, but something like this may work: https://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/