# How to get window.pageYOffset

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, scroll

On desktop browsers, we can make use of scrollTop() with JQuery or just window.pageYOffset to get this attribute while we're scrolling.

On mobile, this attribute is not updated until the scroll bar stops. Is there a way to get the value of this attribute while the window is scrolling?

Comment: Nope. At least, not reliably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an authority on this by any means but this looks like it could help: [joshua.paling about iScroll](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16421349/830628)